# Is there a clever way to parse an SQL export into a Rails db seed file written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any tools out there that can take an exported database file written in SQL and convert the tables into seed files for Rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main options

a) Use the connection and execute function in Rails

Example:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
statement  = File.read('db//data/icd_10.sql')
connection.execute(statement)
```

Performs the following SQL statement:

```
=> INSERT INTO `icd_10_ca_codes` (`ICD_10_CA_Code`, `Block`, `Code_id`, `Code_Description`, `Code_Includes`, `Code_Excludes`, `Code_Notes`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
=> VALUES ('G35', '' , 'Multiple sclerosis', 'Multiple sclerosis (of):
• NOS
• brain stem
• cord
• disseminated
• generalized', NULL, NULL);
```

b) Use seed_dump gem to export from your SQL database to the seed file and generate a template filed with data

Example:

```
$gem install seed_dump 
$rake db:seed:dump MODEL=Icd10Code APPEND=true
$rake db:seed --trace
```

Generates the following in the seed file:

```
=> Icd10CaCode.create([
=> { :ICD_10_CA_Code => "G35", :Block => "G35", :Code_id => "", :Code_Description => "Multiple sclerosis", :Code_Includes => "Multiple sclerosis (of):\n• NOS\n• brain stem\n• cord\n• disseminated\n• generalized", :Code_Excludes => nil, :Code_Notes => nil, :created_at => "2013-06-24 20:37:24", :updated_at => "2013-06-24 20:37:28" };
=> ], :without_protection => true )
```

https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump